# Enable tracing of requests and responses with jetty-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a working maven project with a properly configured `jetty-maven-plugin` for tests.

If I run `mvn -X jetty:run`, among all debug outputs, I see the trace of all HTTP requests and responses, including received and sent headers.

Alas, the maven debug output is very verbose. Is there some way to configure the plugin, or jetty itself via its xml files, to get the same trace without all other debug outputs?

Please note that I'm not interested in configuring a simple access log, which won't display headers.

Comment: Please note that I'm aware of alternate tools like `tcpdump` and  `wireshark`, but it's not very handy, especially when using ssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure the Jetty [CustomRequestLog](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CustomRequestLog.html), with this you can supply a custom format code which allows you to output the headers that you want to see. The javadoc explains the usage and the different format codes available. You can easily enable this with jetty `customrequestlog` startup module or copying the `jetty-customrequestlog.xml` file.

If that's not good enough then you could also create your own implementation of the `RequestLog` interface and log whatever you want using the request and response. You can then add this to the server with `server.setRequestLog(...)` or equivalent xml.

Comment: thanks for the idea. But I ended up doing myself the logging from a global filter, especially because I could also log response headers from there. I guess configuring a logger the way you describe it is ok to log request headers, though.

Comment: You can also log both request and response headers from the `RequestLog`. Worth noting that the `RequestLog` will log requests for the whole server compared to the filter approach which just does does a particular web app.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, then. I won't probably go back to use it now that my filter is working, and because I'm happy with webapp logs, but others can find it interesting.